# Cannot see Trace logs when loglevel set to Trace in azure function

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, serverless-framework

Steps to reproduce:

Create a new V2 function app in VS
Select HTTP trigger, paste in the following code:

```cs
log.LogTrace("This is a trace log");
log.LogDebug("This is a debug log");
log.LogInformation("This is an information log");
log.LogWarning("This is a warning log");
log.LogError("This is an error log");
log.LogCritical("This is a critical log");
return new OkResult();
```

Go to host.json, configure as follows:

```js
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingExcludedTypes": "Request",
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": false
      },
      "fileLoggingMode": "always",
      "logLevel": {
        "default": "Trace",
        "Host.Results": "Error",
        "Function": "Trace",
        "Host.Aggregator": "Trace"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Run the host, trigger the HTTP function
Expected result - trace message should appear in the application insights

Actual result:
Query in Application insights

```
union traces
| union exceptions
|union requests
| where timestamp > ago(30d)
| where operation_Id == 'be439155fd015344badd3839da2652a8'
| where customDimensions['InvocationId'] == '6057a32f-0f59-4193-8845-a5f9d972169f'
| order by timestamp asc
| project timestamp, message = iff(message != '', message, iff(innermostMessage != '', innermostMessage, customDimensions.['prop__{OriginalFormat}'])), logLevel = customDimensions.['LogLevel']
```

[image: logs]

```
timestamp [UTC]             message  
8/31/2020, 4:00:58.764 PM   Executing 'Function1' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=6057a32f-0f59-4193-8845-a5f9d972169f)              Information 
8/31/2020, 4:00:58.764 PM   Information Logged  
8/31/2020, 4:00:58.953 PM   error Logged    
8/31/2020, 4:00:58.954 PM   Warning Logged  
8/31/2020, 4:00:58.954 PM   Executed 'Function1' (Succeeded, Id=6057a32f-0f59-4193-8845-a5f9d972169f, Duration=190ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

That json file is not correct. `fileLoggingMode` is not a property of the `applicationInsights` object. Also, the log levels for the Host.Result and Host.Aggregator categories should not be set inside the application insights section. See the [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#logging).

But, besides that, you are having issues because the minimum log category filtering for functions should be lower or equal to the log level of application insights. The default log level in azure functions is `Information` so a trace won't pass through.

Try this:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "always",
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Information",
      "Host.Results": "Information",
      "Function": "Trace",
      "Host.Aggregator": "Information"
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingExcludedTypes": "Request",
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": false
      },
      "logLevel": {
        "default": "Trace"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Given the example above the log level for the Function category matches the log level of application insights. Otherwise the application insights log provider won't be able to pick up the logs and send them as TraceTelemetry to Application Insights.

Comment: Thanks peter. Your response helped me to fixed this issue. Yes I did couple of mistakes in json file and with your reference I fixed those  and its working fine. Thanks Again.

Comment: @RamanMiddha great to be of assistance. If the answer is right for you, please accept it like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)