# Why are my logs not retrieved by application insights?

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, ilogger

I have this azure function app, in which I have created a startup file, such that I can run a start procedure once
before the http trigger is avaiable.

```
using HubspotFormsRetriever.DatabaseContexts;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights;

// registering that this is the startup file. 
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Retriever.Startup))]
namespace Retriever
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddDbContext<HubspotModelContext>();
            builder.Services.AddLogging(options => 
            {
                options.AddApplicationInsights("Some id"); 
                options.AddFilter<ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>(typeof(SeedingTools).FullName, LogLevel.Trace);
            });
            using var context = new HubspotModelContext();
            SeedingTools.CheckDatabaseAsync(context);
        }
    }
}
```

In this startup I've have added applicationInsights to my logging,assuming that my logs will be included in application insights.

When I call the CheckDatabaseAsync(context)

```
public static class SeedingTools
{
    public static async Task CheckDatabaseAsync(HubspotModelContext dbContext)
    {
        ILogger logger = new LoggerFactory().CreateLogger("SeedingTools");
        bool dbCreated = dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
        logger.LogError($"Database was already created {dbCreated}");
        await SeedDataAsync(dbContext, logger);
    }
}
```

Even the logger that is being injected from startup, is not visible in the startup.

```
public class Retriever
{
    private readonly ILogger<Retriever> _logger;
    private readonly DbModelContext context;
    public Retriever(ILogger<Retriever> log, DbModelContext context)
    {
        _logger = log;
        this.context = context;
        _logger.LogCritical("CheckingDb");
    }

    [FunctionName("Retriever")]
    [OpenApiOperation(operationId: "Run", tags: new[] { "name" })]
    [OpenApiSecurity("function_key", SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey, Name = "code", In = OpenApiSecurityLocationType.Query)]
    [OpenApiParameter(name: "name", In = ParameterLocation.Query, Required = true, Type = typeof(string), Description = "The **Name** parameter")]
    [OpenApiResponseWithBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.OK, contentType: "text/plain", bodyType: typeof(string), Description = "The OK response")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req)
    {
        _logger.LogError("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        string name = context.Database.ProviderName;

        //string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
        //    ? $"This name exists {name}"
        //    : $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";

        return new OkObjectResult(name);
    }
}
```

I make an logError, but don't see this message in application insights when I query

```
traces 
| where customDimensions.LogLevel == "Error"
```

the view is empty?

Am I missing something, why is nothing listed in application insights?

Comment: As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#caveats log service may not be available till configure method completes. Another point, I would suggest to use `ILoggerFactory` instead of creating a new instance.

Comment: [Cannot see Trace logs when loglevel set to Trace in azure function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63674551/cannot-see-trace-logs-when-loglevel-set-to-trace-in-azure-function), [Create filter rules in configuration with appsettings.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger#create-filter-rules-in-configuration-with-appsettingsjson) and [Application Insights not recognising logLevel settings in host.json](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/5250)

Answer (score 0):

> ILogger logger = new LoggerFactory().CreateLogger("SeedingTools");

^ This will not work. You have enabled logging and added ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider to a different LoggerFactory at the startup. You must create Loggers from the same LoggerFactory inorder for this to work.

Normally you'd just inject `ILogger` to the instance where you do the logging. If you are doing from a static `CheckDatabaseAsync` method, then the caller must pass the right ILogger or LoggerFactory to it.

Comment: How should the caller do that?
Besides, the injected Ilogger logs are not logged either.

Comment: What I ended up doing, but the answer is still not answered.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you add `services.AddLogging()` in your Startup class and that's it. [Application Insights is added to Azure functions automatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#logging-services).

Inside your function, instead if calling the `Ilogger<T>` from your constructor, try calling `Ilogger` from the function header like this:

```
public Retriever(DbModelContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        _logger.LogCritical("CheckingDb");
    }

    [FunctionName("Retriever")]
    [OpenApiOperation(operationId: "Run", tags: new[] { "name" })]
    [OpenApiSecurity("function_key", SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey, Name = "code", In = OpenApiSecurityLocationType.Query)]
    [OpenApiParameter(name: "name", In = ParameterLocation.Query, Required = true, Type = typeof(string), Description = "The **Name** parameter")]
    [OpenApiResponseWithBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.OK, contentType: "text/plain", bodyType: typeof(string), Description = "The OK response")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger _logger)
    {
        _logger.LogError("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        string name = context.Database.ProviderName;

        //string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
        //    ? $"This name exists {name}"
        //    : $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";

        return new OkObjectResult(name);
    }
```